# MongoDB Class Document not exist symfony 2

Tags: mongodb, symfony

I just freshly installed symfony2 with fosuserbundle and DoctrinemongodbBundle.

FOS is configured with mongodb and works well

I try to set and get some data inside a mongodb document

Here is my document:

```
<?php
// src/Acme/UserBundle/Document/Video.php

namespace Tube\VideoBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class Video
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="auto")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Int
     */
    protected $uid;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $type;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $embed;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $url;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return id $id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set uid
     *
     * @param int $uid
     * @return self
     */
    public function setUid($uid)
    {
        $this->uid = $uid;
        return $this;
    }

    ......
}
```

Here my controller:

```
<?php

namespace Tube\VideoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Tube\VideoBundle\Document\Video;


class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function addVideo($uid, $type, $embed, $url)
    {
        $video = new Video;

        $video->setUid($uid);
        $video->setType($type);
        $video->setEmbed($embed);
        $video->setUrl($url);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($video);
        $em->flush();

        return new Response($video->getId());
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $video = $this->addVideo(1, "YouTube", '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/pA8Kzh_GWvw?list=UUEJFNw_gfbaoJnHfFguvI_w" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>', "http://youtu.be/pA8Kzh_GWvw?list=UUEJFNw_gfbaoJnHfFguvI_w");

        return $this->render('TubeVideoBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('id' => $video));
    }
}
```

Symfony error:

```
The class 'Tube\VideoBundle\Document\Video' was not found in the chain configured namespaces
```

Where I'm wrong?

config.yml

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true

doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: mongodb://localhost:27017
            options: {}
    default_database: test_database
    document_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true
```

Stack trace:

```
[1] Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException: The class 'Tube\VideoBundle\Document\Video' was not found in the chain configured namespaces 
    at n/a
        in /usr/local/var/www/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php line 37

    at Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException::classNotFoundInNamespaces('Tube\VideoBundle\Document\Video', array())
        in /usr/local/var/www/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/MappingDriverChain.php line 113

    at Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain->loadMetadataForClass('Tube\VideoBundle\Document\Video', object(ClassMetadata))
        in /usr/local/var/www/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php line 117

    at Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->doLoadMetadata(object(ClassMetadata), null, false, array())
        in /usr/local/var/www/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php line 318

    at Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata('Tube\VideoBundle\Document\Video')
        in /usr/local/var/www/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php line 211

    at Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor('Tube\VideoBundle\Document\Video')
        in /usr/local/var/www/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php line 295

    at Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getClassMetadata('Tube\VideoBundle\Document\Video')
        in /usr/local/var/www/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 1610

    at Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->doPersist(object(Video), array('000000003c91b7fb0000000117989f94' => object(Video)))
        in /usr/local/var/www/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 1583

    at Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->persist(object(Video))
        in /usr/local/var/www/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php line 624

    at Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->persist(object(Video))
        in /usr/local/var/www/Symfony/src/Tube/VideoBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php line 26

    at Tube\VideoBundle\Controller\DefaultController->addVideo('1', 'YouTube', '&lt;iframe width=&quot;560&quot; height=&quot;315&quot; src=&quot;//www.youtube.com/embed/pA8Kzh_GWvw?list=UUEJFNw_gfbaoJnHfFguvI_w&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;', 'http://youtu.be/pA8Kzh_GWvw?list=UUEJFNw_gfbaoJnHfFguvI_w')
        in /usr/local/var/www/Symfony/src/Tube/VideoBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php line 34

    at Tube\VideoBundle\Controller\DefaultController->indexAction()
        in  line 

    at call_user_func_array(array(object(DefaultController), 'indexAction'), array())
        in /usr/local/var/www/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2987

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
        in /usr/local/var/www/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2949

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
        in /usr/local/var/www/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3098

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
        in /usr/local/var/www/Symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2348

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
        in /usr/local/var/www/Symfony/web/app_dev.php line 28
```

Comment: Did you register your VideoBundle in AppKernel.php?

Comment: yes its register in appkernel

Comment: Ok going off of little information then. Can you provide more information on your relevant config? Did you cover all of the items highlighted in this article? http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html

Comment: Hi cristian, I just addedd my config yml for doctrine and yes I followed the how to with attention :/

Comment: If your default controller is responding to requests properly, and it's in the VideoBundle (I missed that initially), your autoloading should work and your Video document should also load (assuming it's in the Document directory alongside your Controller directory) since it would use the same setup to load a Document or Controller. Can you post a stack trace with line numbers?

Comment: Also, you are using a document manager, not entity manager. $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); should be $dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager(); or $dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb.odm.document_manager'); (also updating $em to $dm on the persist/flush calls).

Comment: stack trace is added! I edit right now the code about entity/document manager. thanks for that!

Comment: Any update/updated stack trace after changing to use the document manager? Some other SO threads mention this can happen if you're working with multiple document/entity managers.